# Linux: FIFO scheduler isn't working as expected

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, fifo

I am currently trying to work with Linux FIFO schedulers.

I want to run two processes: process A and process B with the same priority in a FIFO way.
To do this, I have made a shell script in which I run process A first, followed by process B. In FIFO format, process B should start its execution only after the completion of process A, i.e., there should be no overlapping between the execution of these processes. But this isn't what is happening.
I am actually observing that both of the processes are running in an overlapping fashion, i.e., the print statements are printing in both the processes in an interleaved format.

Here is the code of the shell script.

```
gcc -o process_a process_a.c
gcc -o process_b process_b.c
sudo taskset --cpu-list 0 chrt -f 50 ./process_a &
sleep 0.1
sudo taskset --cpu-list 0 chrt -f 50 ./process_b &
sleep 30
exit
```

To make sure that both the processes run on the same CPU, I have used `taskset` command. Also, I am using `chrt` command to set the scheduler.

Here is the code for process_a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Process A begins!\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    long long int i=0, m = 1e8;
    while(i<2e10){
        if(i%m == 0){
            printf("Process A running\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("Process A ended \n");
    fflush(stdout);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for process_b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Process B begins!\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    long long int i=0, m = 1e8;
    while(i<2e10){
        if(i%m == 0){
            printf("Process B running\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("Process B ended \n");
    fflush(stdout);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me understand why this is happening.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess here, but are you sure that `taskset` operates on your processes and not `chrt`?

Comment: "process B should start its execution only after the completion of process A" Only true if A does not block.

Comment: How many CPUs do you have? Really just one?  Even $10 mini Linux boards have multiple cores now and can run multiple FIFO processes at the same time.

Comment: @TrentP, I am using a 4-core CPU... To ensure that both the processes run on the same CPU, I used `taskset`. However, now I will check this once again too that they are actually running on the same core or not.

Comment: Did you compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O` ?

Comment: @Balise, Yes I tried that too, but the warnings that came were of unused parameters only.

Comment: Please, don't use floating point literals to initialize integers, you'll get surprises, as the precission of a `double` is far far less than that of a `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

The `sched(7)` manual page says this:

> A `SCHED_FIFO` thread runs until either it is blocked by an I/O request, it is preempted by a higher priority thread, or it calls `sched_yield(2)`.

In this case, you're performing an I/O request to the terminal via `printf`, which calls `write` under the hood.  Your file descriptor is in blocking mode, so it is likely that at least some blocking occurs in this case since generally I/O is slow, especially to terminals, causing the other process to run.

If you wanted a better example of one process preventing the other from running, you'd probably want to do something like write into a shared memory segment instead, which wouldn't be blocked by an I/O request.

Comment: This is correct, but I'll add that there is another way.  The default Linux scheduler parameters have a failsafe that prevents a RT process from using fully 100% CPU.  Some very small amount of time will be given to other processes.  Otherwise an RT process that doesn't block or finish is an instant unkillable system hang.